# Async() methods in WCF test client

Tags: c#, wcf, testing, client, server

I wrote a simple WCF service and when I debug the project I get a WCF client window in which each service method has an async() version (for example, for the method ConnectMessages() from the service there is a new method GetMessagesAsync(). However, the async methods are shadowed and marked with a red 'x' and ahve the following caption:

This operation is not supported in wcf test client because it uses system.threading.tasks.task

my questions are: why does each method have an async version and why are these async marked as unfunctional? what does this mean?

Answer (score -1):

When we normally call a service method our code is executing sequentially ans it waits for the response returned by service and code execution is blocked, when we use **Async** methods, our code does not blocks and continues its execution and services fires an event when it returns response.

If i have called service synchronously:

```
var result = ReportClientObj.GetUserCoordinatesReport(searchParams);
  if(result == null)  // this line will not ewxecute until above line of code executes and completes
  {
   // do something
  }
```

if i use async code execution will not stop:

```
var result = ReportClientObj.GetUserCoordinatesReportAsync(searchParams);
  if(result == null)  // this line will execute and will not wait for above call to complete due to asynshronous call and this will bang
  {
   // do something
  }
```

For doing above thing in Async we have to use its Completed event

Register it's event:

```
    reportClient.GetUserCoordinatesReportCompleted += reportClient_GetUserCoordinatesReportCompleted;
```

and then catch the comleted event, use its reponse:

```
void reportClient_GetUserCoordinatesReportCompleted(object sender, GetUserCoordinatesReportCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Use Result here 
  var Result = e.Result;
  if(Result !=null)
  {
    // do something
  }
}
```

See here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/building-and-consuming-async-wcf-services-in-.net-framework-4.5.htm

Comment: It is still not clear to me why these methods are shadowed and marked with a red 'x'. Can I still use them? Also, it is not clear to how I use the event in your example. Do I have to declare the event? Should I call the async() method inside the vent handler?

Comment: no when you add service reference there are options where we select to use Task based of asynchronous, check this article:http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/building-and-consuming-async-wcf-services-in-.net-framework-4.5.htm

Comment: Thank you. This article seems to be just what I need.

Comment: This answer's body doesn't seem the address the question at all. It should not rely on comments and external links.